# My keyboard layout languages settings keep reverting to English only

Tags: windows-10, sleep, input-languages

I have both Hebrew and English installed on my computer. I usually can switch back and forth normally. However, whenever I sleep the laptop, when I reopen it, I cannot switch between languages, and can only input in English until I reset the machine.

This has been going on since I updated Windows 10 to its newest version (it's currently version 1903). (I had been avoiding it to keep epub functionality in Edge.) It's also possible that it happened because I added an additional user account, where before I was the only user.

This happens even if I set  Hebrew as my default language (after I sleep it), it still only can type in English.

Although settings says both English and Hebrew are installed, and pressing alt-shift is enabled to switch between them, this again only works until I sleep. Even if I set hotkeys, the hotkeys settings disappear after I sleep. So does the language bar.

Since I must type in both Hebrew and English, I essentially have no sleep function, as Hebrew will not work at all after I sleep, even if I select it from the settings.

Comment: What edition of Windows do you have installed?  What language is that edition?  Have you tried to reinstall the language that was added?

Comment: @Ramhound english. Windows 10 fully updated. Yes.

Comment: Be specific “fully updated” isn’t specific enough.  I also asked if you uninstalled the Hebrew language pack.  I also asked for which edition your running’s. Instead of a comment add this critical information to your question.  There are more than 5 “current” versions of Windows (1507,1511,1607,1703,1709,1803,1809,1903).  So please be specific when providing details.

Comment: @Ramhound I did reinstall and uninstall. WIndows 10 pro. Not sure how to find out the exact number.

Comment: Tell us the last cumulative update that was installed or use **winver**

Comment: @Ramhound version 1903

Comment: So have you tried reinstalling the language pack, one of the many problems I have seen, is language packs and feature updates.  Reinstalling them almost always works

Comment: @Ramhound Tried it. It doesn't help. Whenever I sleep from one username and switch to the other, I can't type in Hebrew till I restart.